# JSON parse error : no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (3);

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Estoy haciendo una petición POST como esta:

```
{
    "fechaInsercion": "2021-04-28 09:57:02",
    "fechaModificacion": "2021-04-28 09:57:02",
    "tipoDoc": 12,
    "entidad": 1,
    "oficina": 1,
    "referencia": 1,
    "moneda": {"id":3}
}
```

Este JSON trata de la clase Remesa.java en la que remesa tiene una relación 1 a 1 con una moneda(Moneda.java), y aquí el problema que tengo es que al hacer el POST no quiero que la propiedad "moneda" para añadirle un "id" , tenga que poner **"moneda":{"id":3}** , sino que lo que quiero es **"moneda":3** , y que detecte que ese 3 por ejemplo sea el id de la moneda. Ejemplo:

```
{
    "fechaInsercion": "2021-04-28 09:57:02",
    "fechaModificacion": "2021-04-28 09:57:02",
    "tipoDoc": 12,
    "entidad": 1,
    "oficina": 1,
    "referencia": 1,
    "moneda": 3
}
```

Entonces , al poner **"moneda":3** me está poniendo el error de :

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.konecta.cashletter.dominio.Moneda` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (3); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.konecta.cashletter.dominio.Moneda` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (3)
```

¿Alguien sabe como solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale , lo he arreglado añadiendo a la clase Moneda.java éste constructor:

```
public Moneda(Long id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }
```

De esta manera puede añadir esa moneda por el ID , no sé por qué se debe 100%. Aún así dejo la respuesta por si alguien le sirve , y por si alguien puede ilustrarnos más

Answer (score 0):

El error en mi caso estaba en mi modelo porque le agregué `@NotBlank` a un `double` y eso me traía ese error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]